# Generate Pdf Using QCoreApplication in QT

Tags: visual-c++, qt4

I would like to generate Pdf using `QCoreApplication` instead of `QApplication` in QT.Is there solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you googled it before you asked?

Comment: ya ,,but i did not get any relavent answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can create/write a pdf file using QCoreApplication. Writing a PDF file at the very mimimum requires rendering the text in a desired font. That, as far as I know, can be done only using a QPrinter, which requires QApplication to be constructed.

There are several open source pdf libraries which allow you to create pdf files. You could try iText, libHaru, or podofo for writing pdf files.

Comment: thanq marcus ,,,i will try and i will get back to u soon